# Xpath type locator for the Login input

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

I want to understand this but I am kinda confused:

> Taking the following login as an example, if we want to identify an
> xpath type locator for the Login input, what would it be the most appropriate option as a good practice.    Note that all
> of these options work correctly when locating the Login (input)
> object.

Image:

[image]

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the following suggestions:

[image: suggestions]

The most canonical [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447) would be **option b**:

```
//input[@id='user_login']
```

Comment: Hey pal, thanks for replying. Why would you choose the canonical one?

Comment: From [merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/canonical), **canonical**: _conforming to a general rule or acceptable procedure : ORTHODOX_

Comment: Gonna take a look, thanks for helping me! :)